# Windows 10 Linux subsystem ssh-agent not persisting added identities

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-agent

I have started using my Windows 10 for Rails development and am using Linux subsystem for the same.

Recently I faced an issue connecting to a remote machine via SSH from the terminal. The public key is already available on the remote machine.

After doing some troubleshooting based on the resources I found on web I noticed that SSH agent was not running because `ssh-add -l` command didn't provided the expected output.

To make the SSH agent launch on startup I followed the instructions at https://github.com/abergs/ubuntuonwindows#2-start-an-bash-ssh-agent-on-launch and it worked flawlessly.

Now that SSH agent launches automatically I added my identity file to it using command `ssh-add path/to/identity/file`..

Note that while generating SSH keys I used custom file name **id_work_gmail** and **id_work_gmail.pub**. Thus I had to add it to the agent using above command.

After doing that I can successfully connect to remote machine through SSH.

Until this everything was going smooth. However as soon as I closed each of the [Cmder](http://cmder.net/) Ubuntu Bash consoles and started a new one `ssh-add -l` informed **The agent has no identities.**. So again I had to add my custom-named identity file to the agent.

So this is something I need to do every-time I kill each of the Ubuntu Bash consoles and start a fresh one.

My question is how can we make the `ssh-add path/to/identity/file/custom-named` action persistent like it happens on actual Ubuntu machine. And am curious to know what is it that makes it a one-time activity on Ubuntu machine and a repeated activity on Windows 10 Linux Subsystem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And am curious to know what is it that makes it a one-time activity on Ubuntu machine and a repeated activity on Windows 10 Linux Subsystem.

Normally, the `ssh-agent` runs in your session so it does not close earlier than you logout from your account in Linux.

If you use it from WLS and close the (probably) last window, it does reasonable cleanup and probably stops your `ssh-agent`, which is reasonable and safe to remove sensitive data from memory.

> My question is how can we make the ssh-add path/to/identity/file/custom-named action persistent like it happens on actual Ubuntu machine.

Just do not close that window (or leave one opened on background ... it might help too). Or configure `ssh` to do that step automatically when you use the key for the first time. Just write to your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host server-you-are-connecting.to
  IdentityFile path/to/identity/file/custom-named
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. Your suggestion of using option `AddIdentityToAgent yes` resulted in `Bad configuration option: addidentitytoagent`. I referred the manual at https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config and there I could not find that option in supported options and hence I guess this error.

Comment: Sorry. I meant `AddKeysToAgent` inestead.

Comment: same error `Bad configuration option: addkeystoagent`

Comment: Then you have old OpenSSH (it works with 7.2 and newer), so either update or go with the first option.

Comment: Thanks I will try to update it. BTW I also found a related SO Post https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269132/146438 on that option.

Comment: I updated the SSH on my WLS however using your suggestion to use a config file and add `AddKeysToAgent` option to it is not proving to be helpful in the original problem I have i.e. after exiting the last session and logging-in again I have to re-add key using ssh-add. I have documented this in a gist https://gist.github.com/jiggneshhgohel/afe96f0d57bdbf8beba305a73905402d.

Comment: Your comments show that you are connecting to `github.com` and not the hosts you defined the option for and therefore it is not applied.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I have added new comments in the gist showing that the issue is resolved.